# Save result from Objectify in human readable form in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, datastore

I am trying to create an Eventlog (ORMSLOG in example), that saves events in human readable form in Datastore.

Doing this should write readable event:

`List<Device> devices = ofy().transactionless().load().type(Device.class).list();
ORMSLOG.log(ORMSLOG.GET_ALL_DEVICES, "Devices found: " + String.valueOf(devices));`

The ORMSLOG is a simple class.

```
public class ORMSLOG {
    public final static String CREATE_DEVICE = "Create Device";
    public final static String GET_ALL_DEVICES = "Get all Devices";

    public static void log(final String event, final String data) {
        ofy().save().entity(new Event(event, data)).now();
    }
}
```

But the data saved in Datastore is not readable and looks like this:

[ORMSLOG data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HJ3d.png)

I need to transform the reference to the object into human readable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just logging the String representation of the objects, which is done by calling the `toString` method. Since you did not override the `toString` method in the `Device` class, you are getting the pointer to the objects. If you override the `toString` method in your Device class to return whatever state you want to return, you would see a much better result. Most IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) have an option to generate `toString` method for you.